# SSL Certificate for local domain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm working in our test lab.  All the machines in our test lab are on the `.foo.bar.baz.com` domain.  I can install our server with an SSL certificate with the common name of `*.foo.bar.baz.com` and it will successfully validate...

```
https://abc.foo.bar.baz.com
https://xyz.foo.bar.baz.com
```

...but will not work for...

```
https://abc
```

which is how a lot of our scripts are designed.  Is there any SSL common name I can use (I tried `*`) that will validate sites without a domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best you can do is a UCC cert that lists all of the hostnames individually.  Here are [instructions on generating a CSR from openssl to do this](http://langui.sh/2009/02/27/creating-a-subjectaltname-sanucc-csr/) (since the standard prompts will not ask for the subjectAltName field).  So you could create a certificate with *.for.bar.baz.com as the Common Name, and then list the hostnames in the alt_names section/

Comment: That solution will probably work.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "site without a domain" unless you're accessing by IP only. In the case of https://abc, `abc` IS your FQDN.

There is unfortunately no way of having a certificate that does both versions of the wildcard you're after. You could work on Subject Alternate Names for each certificate, but then that obviously needs to be re-issued every time there's a new server added.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to give the check to the other answer for providing the link, but this information was good too!

Comment: @pace - all good. DerfK probably needs the rep more than I do anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

As i have read and understand from name cheap community its not possible to secure only the fifth level domain as you said 'abc', Better to use Multi Domain SAN SSL certificate which can secure different top level domain name, different second level domain name, different IPs or different Server names.